# Rollback Database Update After Refreshing a Page (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, oracle, adodb

I have a php application where the user can make some changes to an oracle database with `adodb`.

After the request is executed, the page is refreshed and the user can see the result.

How would I add an undo option of this UPDATE after refreshing the page?

I've tried `beginTrans()`, but it seems like it automatically rollbacks after the php script is executed.

Comment: PHP scripts have ceased execution by the time the HTML output is being displayed.  Each page refresh is a new database session.  You'll have to implement your own rollback logic if you've already committed a change

Comment: So do I need to do something like UPDATE which nulify my previous UPDATE?

Answer (score 0):

Database transactions are tied to a single connection.  Connections are normally closed when the PHP script finishes and trying to make a connection persist for the same user on multiple requests would be very problematic.

As much as possible, it's best to treat HTTP requests as stateless.  Meaning, changes should be committed to the database at the end of every request and an undo in HTTP should probably not be concerned with rolling back a previous transaction, but also actually committing changes in the database.